# Python call C library - undefined symbol: LVCGenRTEnd

Tags: python, c, python-2.7, labview

How can I solve this **undefined symbol: LVCGenRTEnd** while loading .so library?

```
    >>> Traceback (nost recent call last):
        File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
        File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 435, in LoadLibrary return self._dlltype(name)
        File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 357, in __init__ self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
    OSError: ./libIncrement.so: undefined symbol: LVCGenRTEnd
```

I compile basic C code Increment.c to **libIncrement.so**.

```
    # gcc -c -fPIC Increment.c -o LIncrement.o 
    # gcc LIncrement.o -shared -o libIncrement.so
```

C code  was generated form  Windows Labview 2017 in C Generator 2017.
I try load libIncrement.so in python 2.7 on Fedora 25

```
    from ctypes import *
    dl = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(./libIncrement.so)
```

*Thank you very much for any help you can provide.*

Comment: Obviously it needs the symbol LVCGenRTEnd that is provided *elsewhere*...

Comment: Yes I thing so, but where can I find it?